# Android studio Only Showing Relative Layout

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

How to fix the two layouts for Android Studio?
After updating Android Studio, it had two different layouts: relative layout and another layout which simulated how it would look on the phone.

How to get the other layout? Thank you.

How it's looks now:[image: Layout Snap]

Comment: You can use coding instead of drag and drop for relative layout `<RelativeLayout>` and so on

Answer (score 2):

[image: click there]
Use the "Show Design + Blueprint" option.